# Transform list into numpy matrix

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix `X` and a list `centres`. I want to create a new numpy matrix `td_X`.

I want to populate `td_X` with the which is made up of the rows of `X` where the index is equal to centres. In pseudocode:

```
for each in centers:
  td_X.append(X[eacj])
```

How can I do this using Python?

Comment: Did you try anything at all??? even `np.array(x)`???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since that middle dimension is size 1, just reshape or squeeze it.

```
x = np.array(alist)
x = np.squeeze(x)  # or
x = x.reshape(45, 5785)  # or
x = x[:,0,:]
```

You can remove the extra layer of nesting in the list, but this kind of reshaping is so much easier with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

From `x[0]`, you have an extra level of list wrapped around. Removing it by indexing should get you there:

```
x = np.array([l[0] for l in x])
```

---

Here is a small example:

```
x = [[[1,2]], [[2,3]], [[4,5]]]

np.array(x).shape
# (3, 1, 2)

np.array([l[0] for l in x]).shape
# (3, 2)

np.array([l[0] for l in x])
# array([[1, 2],
#        [2, 3],
#        [4, 5]])
```

Comment: This still produces an array with dimensions: `(45, 1, 5785)`

Comment: Did you assign the result back to `x`?

Comment: No to a different variable.

Comment: That's interesting. I just added a small but similar example. Seems to work as expected.